# How to predict for test query with multinomial Bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

Trying out Multinomial Naive Bayes. My data set (df) looks like this :

[image]

I created training and test dataset and did train the model. This is what I tried so far:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import NaiveBayes
# Initialise the model
nb = NaiveBayes(smoothing=1.0, modelType="multinomial")
# Fit the model
model = nb.fit(train)
# Make predictions on test data
predictions = model.transform(test)
```

Now how do I predict the top labels for query = "something" ?

Comment: Please make this into a [mcve], including enough data to reproduce the issue. Don't use screenshots.

Comment: `df` is not defined